# After merging two files, one x value gets repeated twice in the plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, xvalue

I have two datasets that I merge into one, and then I make a plot. At this last stage, I get an x value repeated twice ('2 hours'), second point (correct) and also as last x value (wrong). If I plot the individual datasets this problem does not occur. Any idea how to solve the problem?

```
sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)


file_1 = pd.read_excel(r'.......xlsx')
file_1['Light treatment']='Constant'
file_2 = pd.read_excel(r'.......xlsx')
file_2['Light treatment']='Sinusoidal'

frames = [file_1, file_2]
file = pd.concat(frames)


df_new = file.loc[(file['Time']==50.712336)]


ax= sns.lineplot(x="Sampling", y="NPQ", hue="Light treatment", ci=68, 
marker='s', data=df_new)
plt.show()
```

[image: correct figure from file 1]
[image: correct figure from file 1]

[image: wrong figure]

Comment: Can you make sure that the strings '2 hours' are identical in both files (or dataframes)? (e.g. no extra spaces)

Comment: They are identical, each have 117 elements

Comment: I meant as in 'Sampling' values, does the string '2 hours' in file_1 look the same as '2 hours' in file_2 ? Or is one like '2 hours   ' or '   2 hours'

Comment: They look the same. I checked in the row data file.